# Can anyone share the demo link of Magento 2.3.0 PWA Studio?

Tags: localhost, magento2.3.0, pwa

I'm not able to install PWA studio in my localhost wamp server.
So, I want to test Magento 2.3.0 PWA studio.
If anyone knows the demo link of Magento 2.3.0 PWA Studio, Please share the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the latest version of the Magento Venia PWA Theme here

> https://magento-venia.now.sh/

[image: Magento Venia]

Comment: The link is throwing a 503 error. Please check.

Comment: @Hashid this is an environment of Magento it self. The 503 error means that it is temporarily unavailable and perhaps an update will be released with the latest version. Please try again later

Comment: @Hashid it is now already working ;)

Comment: Not working for me. Stuck on loading. Not getting the first byte from server. Maybe I am always trying at the wrong time :P

Comment: @Hashid it should be working. I will add a screenshot to the answer ;)

Comment: @Mr.Lewis I'm trying to checkout using Indian states name, But I'm getting this messages(`State "Karnataka" is not an valid state abbreviation.`) on checkout, Can you share me the valid state name, then I can test checkout.

Answer (score 2):

The First Open Source PWA Theme For Magento with 
React, Redux, GraphQL  [for more visit](https://scandipwa.com/)

> https://demo.scandipwa.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working demo of latest Magento PWA build (Venia theme) here:

> https://www.codilar.com/blog/magento-2-pwa-demo-venia/

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo of Magento 2.3 PWA.

https://m2pwa.emizentech.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think they have moved the demo site to:
https://venia.magento.com/